# Benchmark results ForkJoin vs Disruptor?

Tags: jmh

I have run this [DisruptovsFJ](https://github.com/shipilev/disrupting-fjp) Mirco-Benchmarks written by `Aleskey Shipilev`, where ForkJoin and the Disruptor library performance is compared.

The results I have using JDK1.8.40 on a Linux platform i5:

```
Benchmark                     Score,     Score Error (99.9%),Unit,Param: slicesK,

Disruptor.run,              939.801405,   20.741961,ms/op,   50000,0,10
ForkJoin.run,               1175.263451,  0.595711, ms/op,   50000,0,10
ForkJoinRecursive.run       771.854028,   26.022542,ms/op,   50000,0,10
ForkJoinRecursiveDeep.run,  1356.697011,  28.666325,ms/op,   50000,0,10
ForkJoinReuse.run,          7974.180793,  49.604539,ms/op,   50000,0,10
```

The first part of the results for `slicesK < 50000` were expected as the `Disruptor` is using a RingBuffer and a mechanism that makes it much efficient in concurrent context.

Now when `slicesK >= 50000` the `Disruptor` test is less performant than ForkJoinRecursiveDeep, and ForkJoinReuse.
Can someone explain to me those results ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer :

Your Disruptor usable Ring Buffer is somehow full at slicesK >= 50000 which is cause the performance to drop.

***Notes :***

For very high performance the ring buffer, and its contents, should fit in L3 CPU cache for exchanging between threads. If the ring buffer is used for a replay scenario, such as market data or network recovery, it may be larger and have obvious performance implications from the cache misses.

---

### [image: Buffer]

---

One of the Sequencer's roles is to ensure that publication does not wrap the Ring Buffer. To do this none of the downstream consumer may have a Sequence that is lower than the Ring Buffer's Sequence less the size of the Ring Buffer. However using the graph of dependencies an interesting optimization can be made
[image: Disruptor with a set of dependent consumers.]

---

[image]

------------------- ^ Thread 1 ^ ------------------------------------------------------------ ^ Thread 2 ^ ----------

---

[image]

---

***Links :***

[Dissecting the Disruptor : What's so special about a ring buffer ?](http://mechanitis.blogspot.be/2011/06/dissecting-disruptor-whats-so-special.html)

[Disruptor FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/disruptor/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

[The LMAX Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)

[LMAX Disruptor Info Page](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Introduction)

[Wiki : Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) (Disruptor does not use pointers)

[Other Circular buffer wiki](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)